# Tratar retorno do curl no Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

Estou montando um shellscript e envia um json file a um webservice, o retorno é o seguinte:

```
{"success":false,"errorCode":3,"message":"Authenticity Token invalido"}
```

Estou tentanto, usando comandos do Linux (shell script), jogar o false em uma variável o a mensagem de erro em outra, mas por não ter espaço não estou conseguindo com o awk, da seguinte forma:

```
SUCCESS=$(echo $RESULT | awk -F ':' '/success/ {print $2}')
ERROR=$(echo $RESULT | awk -F ':"' '/message/ {print $2}')
```

O retorno de ambos, respectivamente, é:

```
false,"errorCode"
Authenticity Token invalido"}
```

Como retornar só true ou false e a mensagem com awk, cut ou outro comando?

Comment: Para retornar true ou false eu consegui executando o awk duas vezes:

SUCCESS=$(echo $RESULT | awk -F ':' '/success/ {print $2}' | awk -F ',' '/false|true/ {print $1}')

Mas acho que possa ter uma forma mais eficiênte.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de resolver esse tipo de coisa com `bash` é utilizar expressões regulares para "limpar" a string de retorno e adicionar separadores que possam depois ser tratados com uma ferramenta de corte.

Usando a funcionalidade de *rematch* do sed, você substitui toda a string em questão só pelos trechos necessários, com um separador exclusivo entre eles, como ponto-e-vírgula:

```
> RESULT='{"success":false,"errorCode":3,"message":"Authenticity Token invalido"}';
> echo $RESULT | sed -r 's/\{"success":(true|false).*"message":"(.*)"\}/\1;\2/';
false;Authenticity Token invalido
```

Utilizando os parênteses na expressão regular, o conteúdo que eles cercam é passado para as variáveis numéricas do *rematch*, no caso `\1` e `\2`. Assim você está substituindo a string inteira por essas duas variáveis, separadas pelo ponto-e-vírgula.

De posse dessa string de saída, pode atribuí-la a diferentes variáveis setando o caractere de separador da shell igual ao ponto-e-vírgula escolhido, e utilizar o `read`, tudo em uma só operação:

```
> IFS=';' read SUCCESS MESSAGE <<< $(echo $RESULT | sed -r 's/\{"success":(true|false).*"message":"(.*)"\}/\1;\2/');
> echo $SUCCESS;
false
> echo $MESSAGE;
Authenticity Token invalido
```

Se preferir você pode, claro, executar dois `sed` como fez na pergunta:

```
> SUCCESS=$(echo $RESULT | sed -r 's/\{"success":(true|false).*/\1/');
> MESSAGE=$(echo $RESULT | sed -r 's/.*"message":"(.*)"\}/\1/');
> echo $SUCCESS;
false
> $MESSAGE;
Authenticity Token invalido
```

Answer (score 1):

O ideal neste tipo de problema é usar ferramentas que reconheçam o formato JSON.

Exemplo com o **jq**

```
$ S=$(jq -r .success <<< $RESULT)
$ M=$(jq -r .message <<< $RESULT)
$ echo $M
Authenticity Token invalido
```